# What folder structure does Swagger Codegen generate for OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: swagger, swagger-codegen, openapi

What is the default file/folder structure generated by Swagger Codegen for OpenAPI 3.0 definitions?

Comment: Folder structure of what, exactly? If you mean an API definition file in the OpenAPI format, it can be a single YAML/JSON file. Do you maybe mean the code generated by [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen)?

Comment: Yes, the code/all default files generated by Swagger Codegen

Answer (score 0):

The file/folder structure generated by Swagger Codegen depends on the output target – Java, PHP, Swift, etc.

It's easiest to see it for yourself – simply paste your spec into http://editor.swagger.io, then generate the desired server or client, and examine the result.